# Regex to test if a string ends with a number

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to test if a string ends with a a digit.  I expect the following Java line to print true.  Why does it print false?

```
System.out.println("I end with a number 4".matches("\\d$"));
```

Comment: This may also be related to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627545/java-regexp-problem-www-vs-www

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Java Regex, there's a difference between [`Matcher.find()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) (find a match anywhere in the String) and [`Matcher.matches()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) (match the entire String).

String only has a `matches()` method (implemented equivalent to this code:`Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(this).matches();`), so you need to create a pattern that matches the full String:

```
System.out.println("I end with a number 4".matches("^.*\\d$"));
```

Comment: Actually, more simply:
System.out.println("I end with a number 4".matches(".*\\d"));

but the '$' should mean I don't have to specify .* at the beginning.
Why doesn't '$' at the end work?

Comment: The extra backspace removes the escape behaviour. Hence "^.*\\d$" may not work. You can test this in online regex testers like this: http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

Comment: @Kash in Java, the extra backspace is necessary

Comment: @Thor both the `^` and the `$` are entirely optional when doing full matches. They have no effect whatsoever and are only there for clarity

Comment: @Sean, you are right, there is no verbatim in Java like C# has @. My bad.

Comment: @ Sean, Although the .* will also match a single digit and not necessarily a string that ends in a digit. So you may wanna try .+ instead to ensure there is atleast one char before the number

Comment: @Kash true, but that's not the OP's requirement. He wanted to test if the String ends with a digit and nothing else.

Comment: `^` and the `$` are entirely optional ...  I'd rephrase that to be you have to have both or neither, but it is the same in either case.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for anything that ends with (not something followed by a digit).  `.*` not `.+`

Comment: FYI:  Matcher.find is the behavior I'm looking for:
`System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\d$").matcher("I end with a number 4").find());`

Comment: @Thor .+ in this context will also give you anything that ends with a digit AND ensures that there is atleast one char before the digit. For example, if you have a string that has only a digit like "4" and nothing before 4, then .* will match this string and .+ will not. Whereas your string "I end with a number 4" will be matched by both .* and .+

Answer (score 15):

Your regex will not match the entire string but only the last part. Try the below code and it should work fine as it matches the entire string.

```
System.out.println("I end with a number 4".matches("^.+?\\d$"));
```

You can test this for a quick check on online regex testers like this one: 
http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html. This also gives you what you should use in the Java code in the results with appropriate escapes.

The **.+** will ensure that there is atleast one character before the digit.
The **?** will ensure it does a lazy match instead of a greedy match.

Comment: There's no point doing a lazy match in this case.  We *want* the `.+` to gobble up the whole string right away.  Then it will back off one position to compare the last character to `\d`, which is the only thing we care about.

Answer (score 2):

Your RegEx expression is [slightly off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Try this:

```
System.out.println("I end with a number 4".matches("^.*\\d$"));
```

You can also simply test like this if you are evaluating a line at a time:

```
System.out.println("I end with a number 4".matches(".*\\d"));
```

Your original expression, without .* only tested to see whether the string was a number and did not account for text that may precede that number. That's why it was always false.

The following does evaluate to true:

```
System.out.println("4".matches("^\\d$"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("I end with a number 4".matches(".*\\d")); // prints true
```

or

```
String s = "I end with a number 4";
System.out.println(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(s.length()-1)));  // prints true
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
System.out.println("I end with a number 4".matches(".*\\d\$"));
```

Comment: Won't compile, `\$` is illegal in Java