# find a string that end with any number by regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to identify two kinds of string: one end with numbers (or not with) by regular expression.

But I can't classify them by `\d+$` or `^\D*\d*$` or `^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*$`

Does anyone can tell me why? and how to solve this problem..?

Comment: Why, what goes wrong with \d+$ or indeed just \d$ ? Also, what regular expression engine are you using? Different languages and tools have different ones.

Comment: What tool are you using?

Comment: They both take StringNumber and StringNumberString as the same one. I'm using Windows XP and just want to run it on Windows Command Processor

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code, all **relevant** error messages exactly as they appear, and whatever samples you're testing against.

Comment: This may also be related to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690305/regex-to-test-if-a-string-ends-with-a-number .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your answer is quite incomplete, that makes it quite difficult to answer. Your comment does also not clarify anything.

**My guess:**

With your two expressions `^\D*\d*$` and `^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*$`, you can't verify what you are looking for, since the quantifier `*` is also matching 0 occurrences ==> it matches the empty string.

So, `^\D*\d*$` would match any string that has non-digits at the start, or the empty string, followed by digits or the empty string till the end.

Means, this expression would match.

- the empty string
- Foobar
- Foobar 123
- 123

but not

- 123Fooo

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?31bjf)

Comment: thanks for your explanation, now I finally understand why I can't find the string I want. It should be the problem of *. And I already find another solution for my requirement, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

`\d+$` should indeed work (as should `\d$` as minopret noted in his comment) if you use your regex engine's `search` method (as opposed to its `match` method which in some cases requires the entire string to match).

However, both `^\D*\d*$` and `^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*$` are unsuitable for this task because in both of these, the trailing digits are optional (the `*` allows zero repetitions, the  `+` requires at least one).

Comment: Thank you, too!! I thought it's because I didn't understand the influence of     `*`.